# Firebase and Admob package name not updated

Tags: android, firebase, admob

Yesterday I just updated my App package name from **"com.example.xxx"** to **"com.stable.xxx"** and then i uploaded my app on Google Play.

Seems that work all fine but now i saw that on FIREBASE and ADMOB my package name are the old one: "com.example.xxx".

**Should i change it? And how?** Should I recreate a new Firebase and admobs project? Seems to risky for me....

FIREBASE:
[image]

ADMOB:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and the only way to change it is contacting the Firebase Help Service.

By the way work fine even if there are 2 different package name so you can leave it as you have.